# Do we need to manually set Nuxt send gzipped or brotli-compressed files?

Tags: webpack, gzip, nuxt.js, brotli

in order to improve lighthouse score I need to enable `gzip` and/or `brotli` compression so it will increase performance score. I added two webpack plugins to my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
plugins: [
    new CompressionPlugin({
      filename: `[path].gz[query]`,
      algorithm: `gzip`,
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    }),
    new BrotliPlugin({
      asset: `[path].br[query]`,
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  ]
```

And I can confirm, that adding these two plugins is actually creating `.gz` and `.br` versions of my files.

Main questions is: should I do something additionaly with my nuxt config file in order to send these compressed files or nuxt will handle this by itself? Can it be checked on `localhost` (because I've read that `brotli`, for example, is only for HTTPS protocol)?

P.S. I don't use any framework like `express` or `restify`

Answer (score 10):

If you are using nuxt 2, it can be done more easily.

In your `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
import shrinkRay from 'shrink-ray-current'

export default {
  render: {
    compressor: shrinkRay()
  }
}
```

See this article for moore detials https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxtjs-on-brotli